# Flutter Image Alignment

Tags: flutter

How to control alingnment image into scaffold?
its my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageProducts extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageProducts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('PRODUCTS'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'images/pro.jpg',
            width: 250,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to align the image? You can maybe change the value of `crossAxisAlignment`, or wrap your Image widget inside an `Align` widget, or a number of other options - it depends on what you want to achieve. PS I just edited your question to use backticks instead of single quotes surrounding your code, so that it formats correctly :)

Comment: You are already controlling the alignment of your image with the `crossAxisAlignment` and `mainAxisAlignment` attributes within the `Column` widget

Comment: wrap my image into a Row and Column as `      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'images/pro.jpg',
                width: 250,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
`

Answer (score 0):

```
Align(
   alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter
   child:Image.asset(
            'images/pro.jpg',
            width: 250,
          ),),
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include an explanation of why you think this answers the OPs question and an explanation of what the code is doing?